# $y=\frac{1}{x}$, show that $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-1}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}$ and find $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y=\frac{1}{x}$, where $x$ is a function of $t$ show that $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-1}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}$ and find an expression for $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$.

For $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ I keep getting

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{-1}{x^2}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

but the correct answer is apparently

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{-1}{x^2}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}\left({\frac{dx}{dt}}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

The second term is $\big(\frac{d}{dt}(-x^{-2})\big)\frac{dx}{dt}$, and $\frac{d}{dt}(-x^{-2})=2x^{-3}\frac{dx}{dt}$, which explains the second $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are misapplying the product rule. Note that

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( - \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{dx}{dt} \right) & = \left( \frac{d}{dt} \frac{(-1)}{x^2} \right) \frac{dx}{dt} - \frac{1}{x^2} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \frac{dx}{dt} \right) \\
 & = \left( \frac{2}{x^3} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} \right) \frac{dx}{dt} - \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{d^2x }{dt^2} \\
 & = \frac{2}{x^3} \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}.
\end{aligned}$$

You forgot to apply the chain rule to $- \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}g(x)\dot{x}= \dfrac{dg}{dt}\dot{x} + g(x)\ddot{x}
$$
Now let's have $g(x) = -1/x^2$
We have
$$
\dfrac{dg}{dt} = \dfrac{dg}{dx}\dot{x} = \frac{2}{x^3}\dot{x}
$$
So hopefully it is clear to see that you have compute the derivative of $-1/x^2$ wrong?